# Swift 3 FSCalendar select all dates by default

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

I am able to select certain dates while loading the FSCalendar. But I want to load calendar with all dates selected.

```
var attendance_list = [NSManagedObject]();
//After loading data
for attendanceObj in attendance_list{

            let createdDate =   attendanceObj.value(forKey: "date") as! String;
            self.calendar.select(Utils.convertStringToDate(createdDate)) 
}
```

Above code is for selecting dates from an array. 

How can I select all dates without any array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend selecting all dates since the beginning of time to the end of the foreseeable future (also, you cannot do it without an array). What I would recommend is getting the `beginingOfMonth` and `endOfMonth` (both methods are available) in `currentPageDidChange` (another available method). Then set the dates between these two dates to `selected` inside a loop.